# Getting Date from Subscription Data from Braintree Payments

Tags: php, braintree

I'm probably missing something obvious; I'm trying to get the date from the returned data from setting up a subscription with Braintree Payments. My code is as follows:

```
$result1 = Braintree_Subscription::create($subscriptionData);

if ($result1->success) {
    echo("Subscription ID: " . $result1->subscription->id . "<br />");
    echo("Transaction ID: " . $result1->subscription->transactions[0]->id . "<br />");
    echo("Type: " . $result1->subscription->transactions[0]->amount . "<br />");
    //next line has error!!!!!!
    echo("Date: " . $result1->subscription->billingPeriodEndDate . "<br />");
```

The first three "echo's" return what they are supposed to without problem. If I try and get any date value e.g: billingPeriodEndDate, billingPeriodStartDate, createdAt, updatedAt the page just fails, (nothing more is displayed) but there is no error. Error reporting is switched on. Any help appreciated.

If I remove the line where the error is and add the following below

```
echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($result1 AS $item) {
    echo "<li>" . $item . "</li>";
    }
```

Then I can see the entire contents of the array. But I still cannot pull the bit I need out. The date is in the format:

billingPeriodEndDate=Friday, 01-Jan-16 00:00:00 UTC,

As it contains a comma that may be the problem...?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

The date attributes return a DateTime object. Try formatting the date, you may be getting a `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string` error.

```
echo("Date: " . $result1->subscription->billingPeriodEndDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br />");
```

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

Without knowing the exact error I would guess that there is no default timezone set. Try setting one and see if it works.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I already had the following set: date_default_timezone_set('UTC');